# Having directory issues with pygame.font.Font() on Mac

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I am using a Mac, and am having issues calling the directory of a font file. Here is the code:

```
import pygame as pg
ARCADE_FONT = pg.font.Font("~/PycharmProjects/PyGame/Pacman/PAC-FONT.TTF", 15)
```

The directory path I have typed in is exactly what I use in Finder to get to the file, if I press 'Go' and 'Go to Folder', which can also be achieved through pressing the command, shift, and 'G' buttons at once.

Here is the error message:

> OSError: unable to read font file '~/PycharmProjects/PyGame/Pacman/PAC-FONT.TTF'

I think it's the right type of file, but not sure if it's an issue with the directory or the file itself.

Comment: What issues are you having? Error? Loading wrong fonts?

Comment: We can't help you if we don't have any idea of what's going wrong. What 'issues' are you referring to?

Comment: Sorry, thought it was clear. It doesn’t recognize the directory I give. My bad

Answer (score 0):

I think it is because the directory problem. Simply you cannot use symbol '~' to represent your home directory, in your python code.
Try absolute path?
Or a path relative to another path, like using '.' instead.